# USB 3.1 gen 2 flash drive only works when connected through 2 adapters at the same time

Tags: usb, file-transfer, usb-on-the-go, oneplus-7-pro

Okay, this is a very specific question with very specific hardware, so I understand if there isn't an answer.

I recently bought a USB 3.1 gen 2 flash drive with read *and* write speeds of 400MB/s, because it'll speed up my backup process a ton. The flash drive works great on my laptop, desktop, and on other phones. For some reason it just has issues with my OnePlus 7 Pro. If I use a standard USB 3.0 hub to connect it, it doesn't work when connected to the 3.0 port (but works if I connect it to a 2.0 port on the same hub). When I say it doesn't work, I mean it's only recognized half the time at best, so I have to plug it in a few times before my phone sees it, it sometimes randomly disconnects and reconnects, and the transfer speeds are way off. For some reason, files can't be read *at all* when trying to copy *from* the drive, and the write speeds are incredibly slow, though at least it *can* write. When I connect to that 2.0 port, I get standard USB 2.0 speeds for read and write, which are far lower than I'd like, given how fast the flash drive actually is. I've also tried using a straight USB type C to USB 3.1 gen 2 type A cable, and it has the same issues. Both of these methods work on other phones without issue. Also note that I don't have these issues with any other flash drives, but this is the first one I have that uses USB 3.1 gen 2, whereas the best one I had before was USB 3.0 (or as it's now called, USB 3.1 gen 1).

Here's where it gets really weird.

I was trying to troubleshoot every possible scenario, so I decided to try plugging a USB 3.0 type A USB hub into my USB 3.0 type C USB hub (the one I mentioned previously) and *then* plug my flash drive into the USB type A hub, and somehow it fixed all the issues. Suddenly I was getting reads and writes that were capped at the speed of my phone's flash memory, it recognized the flash drive the first time I plugged it in every time, and it never disconnected randomly. The same thing happened when I changed out the USB type C hub for the direct cable as well. Below I've added a crude attempt at making what I'm saying more clear:

Phone > USB-C hub > flash drive    **does not work**

Phone > USB-C to USB 3.1 gen 2 adapter > flash drive    **does not work**

Phone > USB-C hub > USB A hub > flash drive **works**

Phone > USB-C to USB 3.1 gen 2 adapter > USB A hub > flash drive    **works**

When I try to transfer files to and from the flash drive through TWRP, the same issues are present.

I'm using a custom ROM (crDroid) with a stock kernel on Android 11, so I'm going to see shortly if flashing completely back to stock firmware fixes the issue, and will update this post if it does (see edit). I could also grab some system logs if that would help, but I haven't been able to find anything useful through MatLog (at least not that I really understand).

If anyone has any idea why adding another USB hub in would fix whatever issue is going on, I'd greatly appreciate your response even if there is no solution, as it doesn't make any sense to me as is.

EDIT: I've confirmed that flashing back to stock does not solve the issue. I flashed every partition manually with OOS 10 images, and even tried MSM tool, but the problem persists. This means that it may be an issue with my specific model as a whole, but I do not have another OnePlus 7 Pro to test it with. I suppose it could be a hardware issue specific to my individual phone, but I'm unable to determine that myself. In any case, there is *some* bad interaction caused on my phone's end, and it may be caused in part by an issue with the flash drive.

THEORY: My current best theory is that there's some issue with the way that my phone is interpreting the USB 3.1 gen 2 protocol, and somehow adding another USB hub in there helps to "sanitize" it or something of the sort. Since I do not have another USB 3.1 gen 2 flash drive, I'm unable to tell if this is specific to this singular flash drive, or if my theory about the protocol interpretation is correct in the slightest. If anyone knows more about USB protocol, then I'd love to hear what you have to say. I have no idea if my theory makes sense in reality, but it's the only explanation I could think of that made any sense to me.

Comment: Has the hub an own power supply? May be the flash drive requires too much power the OnePlus 7 Pro can't provide?

Comment: @Robert No, it does not have a power supply, and given that it works fine on the USB 2.0 port on the USB-C hub (which is also powered entirely by the phone), I can't imagine that it's a power issue. That was the first thing that came to mind for me too because of the random disconnects, but I don't think that it would be fixed by adding another hub (which should actually drain a bit more power).

Comment: When using USB2 most USB sticks requires much less power than when using USB3.0+ therefore it could be a power issue. You can easily see the power issue by touching the stick when connected to a PC. When connected to USB3 most sticks are getting much hotter than on USB2.

Comment: @Robert I should clarify that when I use the second hub (which provides no external power), it's transferring at USB 3.0 speeds, so it should be drawing the same amount of power as it would be if I were to have simply plugged it into the first hub.